# Submit a form after two clicks on submit Django

Tags: python, django

I'm doing a quiz site, and I have several questions. I currently access a certain category and is shown one question after another after clicking submit. But I would like to click once, show the response on the same screen, and after clicking it again go to the next question. How would I do that?

This is my views.py file:

```
class Perguntas(FormView):

form_class = QuestaoForm
template_name = 'certificacoes/pergunta.html'
template_name_result = 'certificacoes/finalizado.html'

def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    self.dominio = get_object_or_404(Dominio, slug=self.kwargs['slug_dominio'])

    try:
        self.user_logado = self.request.user.is_authenticated()
    except TypeError:
        self.user_logado = self.request.user.is_authenticated

    if self.user_logado:
        self.sessao = Sessao.objects.usuario_sessao(request.user, self.dominio)

    return super(Perguntas, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

def get_form(self, *args, **kwargs):
    if self.user_logado:
        self.questao = self.sessao.pegar_primeira_questao()

    form_class = self.form_class

    return form_class(**self.get_form_kwargs())

def get_form_kwargs(self):
    kwargs = super(Perguntas, self).get_form_kwargs()
    return dict(kwargs, questao=self.questao)

def form_valid(self, form):
    if self.user_logado:
        self.form_valid_usuario(form)
        if self.sessao.pegar_primeira_questao() is False:
            return self.resultado_final_usuario()

    self.request.POST = {}

    return super(Perguntas, self).get(self, self.request)

def form_valid_usuario(self, form):
    progresso = Progresso.objects.get_or_create(usuario=self.request.user)
    hipotese = form.cleaned_data['respostas']
    is_correta = self.questao.checar_correta(hipotese)

    if is_correta is True:
        self.sessao.adicionar_ponto(1)
    else:
        self.sessao.add_incorreta(self.questao)
        # Tenho que mexer aqui para gerar uma nova questão

    self.anterior = {
        'resposta_escolhida': self.questao.alternativa_escolhida(hipotese),
        'resposta_correta': is_correta,
        'questao_resposta': self.questao.enunciado,
        'respostas': self.questao.pegar_alternativas(),
        'alternativa_correta': self.questao.alternativa_correta(),
        'fundamento': self.questao.alternativa_fundamento(hipotese)
    }

    self.sessao.add_usuario_resposta(self.questao, hipotese)
    self.sessao.remover_primeira_questao()

def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super(Perguntas, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
    context['questao'] = self.questao
    context['dominio'] = self.dominio
    context['pontos_atual'] = self.sessao.pontos_atual
    context['tags'] = self.questao.get_tags
    if hasattr(self, 'anterior'):
        context['anterior'] = self.anterior
    return context

def resultado_final_usuario(self):
    resultado = {
        'dominio': self.dominio,
        'sessao': self.sessao,
        'anterior': self.anterior,
        'pontos_atual': self.sessao.pontos_atual
    }

    self.sessao.marcar_certificado_completo()
    self.sessao.delete()

    return render(self.request, self.template_name_result, resultado)
```

Thanks for the help anyway!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use Ajax on you front-end i.e. Use javascript to make a asynchronous request to your Django Backend, you can do it using [vanilla java-script](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/AJAX/Getting_Started#Step_3_%E2%80%93_A_Simple_Example), or use [Jquery](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) if you are already using it in UI. I would suggest first go through the links of Vanilla java-script and understand then use Jquery. A more Django specific example [here](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/08/29/how-to-work-with-ajax-request-with-django.html). Some extracts from the above links for quick view below.

Using Vanilla Java-script:

```js
<script>
(function() {
  var httpRequest;
  document.getElementById("ajaxButton").addEventListener('click', makeRequest);

  function makeRequest() {
    httpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();

    if (!httpRequest) {
      alert('Giving up :( Cannot create an XMLHTTP instance');
      return false;
    }
    httpRequest.onreadystatechange = alertContents;
    httpRequest.open('GET', 'test.html');
    httpRequest.send();
  }

  function alertContents() {
    if (httpRequest.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {
      if (httpRequest.status === 200) {
        alert(httpRequest.responseText);
      } else {
        alert('There was a problem with the request.');
      }
    }
  }
})();
</script>
```

```html
<button id="ajaxButton" type="button">Make a request</button>
```

Using Jquery:

```js
$("ajaxButton").click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  $.ajax({
  method: "POST",
  url: "http://someurl.com/get",
  data: { name: "John", location: "Boston" }
  }).done(function( msg ) {
    alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
  });
});
```

Hope this helps, and points you to the right direction.

Comment: Sorry not answer you, my friend. It was late this day and i wind up sleeping, but thanks, it worked perfectly.